# Passing column name as parameter in Kusto query

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql, azure-monitoring

I need to pass the column name dynamically into the query. While following is syntactically correct it does not really execute the condition on the particular column.

Is this even possible in Kusto?

```
let foo = (duration: timespan, column:string) {
    SigninLogs
    | where TimeGenerated >= ago(duration) 
    | summarize totalPerCol = count() by ['column']
};
//foo('requests')<-- does not work
//foo('user') <-- does not work
//foo('ip')<-- does not work
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try using the `column_ifexists()` function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/columnifexists.

for example:

```
let foo = (column_name:string) {
    datatable(col_a:string)["hello","world"]
    | summarize totalPerCol = count() by column_ifexists(column_name, "")
};
foo('col_a')
```

| col_a | totalPerCol |
| --- | --- |
| hello | 1 |
| world | 1 |